# Max size of XFS file system on Ubuntu 20.04.3?

Tags: xfs

Max size of XFS file system on Ubuntu 20.04.3 ?

Comment: quick search gives me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS#Capacity

Answer (score 0):

While the theoretical maximum size for an XFS file system is 8 exbibytes (8 ✕ 10<sup>18</sup> bytes), Ubuntu itself doesn't impose any lower limitations on the size you can create. The theoretical maximum size of an XFS file system is unattainable due to practical considerations such as available disk space, system resources, and the version of the XFS tools that you're using. These considerations limit the practical maximum size of the XFS file system that you can use on your system.

Comment: Thanks a lot @karel !!!

Comment: @Baxajaun Please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside it. That will change the checkmark's color from gray to green.